# lmfit minimize (or scipy.optimize leastsq) on complex equation/data

Tags: python, optimization, curve-fitting, lmfit, complex-data-types

**Edit:**

Modeling and fitting with this approach work fine, the data in here is not good.
-------------------

I want to do a curve-fitting on a complex dataset. After thorough reading and searching, I found that i can use a couple of methods (e.g. lmfit optimize, scipy leastsq).

But none gives me a good fit at all.

here is the fit equation:

[image]

here is the data to be fitted (list of y values):

```
[(0.00011342104914066835+8.448890220616275e-07j),
 (0.00011340386404065371+7.379293582429708e-07j),
 (0.0001133540327309949+6.389834505824625e-07j),
 (0.00011332170913939336+5.244566142401774e-07j),
 (0.00011331311156154074+4.3841061618015007e-07j),
 (0.00011329383047059048+3.6163513508002877e-07j),
 (0.00011328700094846502+3.0542249453666894e-07j),
 (0.00011327650033983806+2.548725558622188e-07j),
 (0.00011327702539337786+2.2508174567697671e-07j),
 (0.00011327342238146558+1.9607648998100523e-07j),
 (0.0001132710747364799+1.721721661949941e-07j),
 (0.00011326933241850936+1.5246061350710235e-07j),
 (0.00011326798040984542+1.3614817802178457e-07j),
 (0.00011326752037650585+1.233483784504962e-07j),
 (0.00011326758290166552+1.1258801448459512e-07j),
 (0.00011326813100914905+1.0284749122099354e-07j),
 (0.0001132684076390416+9.45791423595816e-08j),
 (0.00011326982474882009+8.733105218572698e-08j),
 (0.00011327158639135678+8.212191452217794e-08j),
 (0.00011327366823516856+7.747920115589205e-08j),
 (0.00011327694366034208+7.227069986108343e-08j),
 (0.00011327915327873038+6.819405851172907e-08j),
 (0.00011328181165961218+6.468392148750885e-08j),
 (0.00011328531688122571+6.151393311227958e-08j),
 (0.00011328857849500441+5.811704586613896e-08j),
 (0.00011329241716561626+5.596645863242474e-08j),
 (0.0001132970129528527+5.4722461511610696e-08j),
 (0.0001133002881788021+5.064523218904898e-08j),
 (0.00011330507671740223+5.0307457368330284e-08j),
 (0.00011331106068787993+4.7703959367963307e-08j),
 (0.00011331577350707601+4.634615394867111e-08j),
 (0.00011332064001939156+4.6914747648361504e-08j),
 (0.00011333034985824086+4.4992151257444304e-08j),
 (0.00011334188526870483+4.363662798446445e-08j),
 (0.00011335491299924776+4.364164366097129e-08j),
 (0.00011337451201475147+4.262881852644385e-08j),
 (0.00011339778209066752+4.275096587356569e-08j),
 (0.00011342832992628646+4.4463907608604945e-08j),
 (0.00011346526768580432+4.35706649329342e-08j),
 (0.00011351108008292451+4.4155812379491554e-08j),
 (0.00011356967192325835+4.327004709646922e-08j),
 (0.00011364164970635006+4.420660396556604e-08j),
 (0.00011373150199883139+4.3672898914161596e-08j),
 (0.00011384660942003356+4.326171366194325e-08j),
 (0.00011399193321804955+4.1493065523925126e-08j),
 (0.00011418043916260295+4.0762418512759096e-08j),
 (0.00011443271767970721+3.91359909722939e-08j),
 (0.00011479600563688605+3.845666332695652e-08j),
 (0.0001153652105925112+3.6224677316584614e-08j),
 (0.00011638635682516399+3.386843079212692e-08j),
 (0.00011836223959714231+3.6692295450490655e-08j)]
```

here is the list of x values:

```
[999.9999960000001,
 794.328231,
 630.957342,
 501.18723099999994,
 398.107168,
 316.22776400000004,
 251.188642,
 199.52623,
 158.489318,
 125.89254,
 99.999999,
 79.432823,
 63.095734,
 50.118722999999996,
 39.810717,
 31.622776,
 25.118864000000002,
 19.952623000000003,
 15.848932000000001,
 12.589253999999999,
 10.0,
 7.943282000000001,
 6.309573,
 5.011872,
 3.981072,
 3.1622779999999997,
 2.511886,
 1.9952619999999999,
 1.584893,
 1.258925,
 1.0,
 0.7943279999999999,
 0.630957,
 0.5011869999999999,
 0.398107,
 0.316228,
 0.251189,
 0.199526,
 0.15848900000000002,
 0.125893,
 0.1,
 0.079433,
 0.063096,
 0.050119,
 0.039811,
 0.031623000000000005,
 0.025119,
 0.019953,
 0.015849000000000002,
 0.012589,
 0.01]
```

and here is the code which works but not the way I want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters

#%% the equation
def ColeCole(params, fr): #fr is x values array and params are the fitting parameters 
    sig0 = params['sig0']
    m = params['m']
    tau = params['tau']
    c = params['c']
    w = fr*2*np.pi
    num = 1
    denom = 1+(1j*w*tau)**c
    sigComplex = sig0*(1.0+(m/(1-m))*(1-num/denom))
    return sigComplex

def res(params, fr, data): #calculating reseduals of fit
    resedual = ColeCole(params, fr) - data
    return resedual.view(np.float)

#%% Adding model parameters and fitting 
params = Parameters()
params.add('sig0', value=0.00166)
params.add('m', value=0.19,)
params.add('tau', value=0.05386)
params.add('c', value=0.80)

params['tau'].min = 0 # these conditions must be met but even if I remove them the fit is ugly!!
params['m'].min = 0

out= minimize(res, params , args= (np.array(fr2), np.array(data)))

#%%plotting Imaginary part

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plotX = fr2
plotY = data.imag
fitplot = ColeCole(out.params, fr2)
ax.semilogx(plotX,plotY,'o',label='imc')
ax.semilogx(plotX,fitplot.imag,label='fit')
#%%plotting real part
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

plotX2 = fr2
plotY2 = data.real
fitplot2 = ColeCole(out.params, fr2)
ax2.semilogx(plotX2,plotY2,'o',label='imc')
ax2.semilogx(plotX2,fitplot2.real,label='fit')
```

I might be doing it completely wrong, please help me if you know the proper solution to do a curve fitting on complex data.

Comment: The fitting works fine, problem is the data. This model cannot be fit to this data.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first converting the complex data to numpy arrays and get real, imag pairs separately and then using lmfit Model to model that same sort of data.  Perhaps something like this:

```
cdata = np.array((0.00011342104914066835+8.448890220616275e-07j,
             0.00011340386404065371+7.379293582429708e-07j,
             0.0001133540327309949+6.389834505824625e-07j,
             0.00011332170913939336+5.244566142401774e-07j,
             0.00011331311156154074+4.3841061618015007e-07j,
             0.00011329383047059048+3.6163513508002877e-07j,
             0.00011328700094846502+3.0542249453666894e-07j,
             0.00011327650033983806+2.548725558622188e-07j,
             0.00011327702539337786+2.2508174567697671e-07j,
             0.00011327342238146558+1.9607648998100523e-07j,
             0.0001132710747364799+1.721721661949941e-07j,
             0.00011326933241850936+1.5246061350710235e-07j,
             0.00011326798040984542+1.3614817802178457e-07j,
             0.00011326752037650585+1.233483784504962e-07j,
             0.00011326758290166552+1.1258801448459512e-07j,
             0.00011326813100914905+1.0284749122099354e-07j,
             0.0001132684076390416+9.45791423595816e-08j,
             0.00011326982474882009+8.733105218572698e-08j,
             0.00011327158639135678+8.212191452217794e-08j,
             0.00011327366823516856+7.747920115589205e-08j,
             0.00011327694366034208+7.227069986108343e-08j,
             0.00011327915327873038+6.819405851172907e-08j,
             0.00011328181165961218+6.468392148750885e-08j,
             0.00011328531688122571+6.151393311227958e-08j,
             0.00011328857849500441+5.811704586613896e-08j,
             0.00011329241716561626+5.596645863242474e-08j,
             0.0001132970129528527+5.4722461511610696e-08j,
             0.0001133002881788021+5.064523218904898e-08j,
             0.00011330507671740223+5.0307457368330284e-08j,
             0.00011331106068787993+4.7703959367963307e-08j,
             0.00011331577350707601+4.634615394867111e-08j,
             0.00011332064001939156+4.6914747648361504e-08j,
             0.00011333034985824086+4.4992151257444304e-08j,
             0.00011334188526870483+4.363662798446445e-08j,
             0.00011335491299924776+4.364164366097129e-08j,
             0.00011337451201475147+4.262881852644385e-08j,
             0.00011339778209066752+4.275096587356569e-08j,
             0.00011342832992628646+4.4463907608604945e-08j,
             0.00011346526768580432+4.35706649329342e-08j,
             0.00011351108008292451+4.4155812379491554e-08j,
             0.00011356967192325835+4.327004709646922e-08j,
             0.00011364164970635006+4.420660396556604e-08j,
             0.00011373150199883139+4.3672898914161596e-08j,
             0.00011384660942003356+4.326171366194325e-08j,
             0.00011399193321804955+4.1493065523925126e-08j,
             0.00011418043916260295+4.0762418512759096e-08j,
             0.00011443271767970721+3.91359909722939e-08j,
             0.00011479600563688605+3.845666332695652e-08j,
             0.0001153652105925112+3.6224677316584614e-08j,
             0.00011638635682516399+3.386843079212692e-08j,
             0.00011836223959714231+3.6692295450490655e-08j))

fr = np.array((999.9999960000001, 794.328231, 630.957342,
          501.18723099999994, 398.107168, 316.22776400000004,
          251.188642, 199.52623, 158.489318, 125.89254, 99.999999,
          79.432823, 63.095734, 50.118722999999996, 39.810717,
          31.622776, 25.118864000000002, 19.952623000000003,
          15.848932000000001, 12.589253999999999, 10.0,
          7.943282000000001, 6.309573, 5.011872, 3.981072,
          3.1622779999999997, 2.511886, 1.9952619999999999, 1.584893,
          1.258925, 1.0, 0.7943279999999999, 0.630957,
          0.5011869999999999, 0.398107, 0.316228, 0.251189, 0.199526,
          0.15848900000000002, 0.125893, 0.1, 0.079433, 0.063096,
          0.050119, 0.039811, 0.031623000000000005, 0.025119, 0.019953,
          0.015849000000000002, 0.012589, 0.01))


data = np.concatenate((cdata.real, cdata.imag))

# model function for lmfit
def colecole_function(x, sig0, m, tau, c):
    w = x*2*np.pi
    denom = 1+(1j*w*tau)**c
    sig = sig0*(1.0+(m/(1.0-m))*(1-1.0/denom))
    return np.concatenate((sig.real, sig.imag))


mod = Model(colecole_function)
params = mod.make_params(sig0=0.002, m=-0.19, tau=0.05, c=0.8)

params['tau'].min = 0

result = mod.fit(data, params, x=fr)

print(result.fit_report())
```

You would then want to plot the results like
    nf = len(fr)
    plt.plot(fr, data[:nf], label='data(real)')
    plt.plot(fr, result.best_fit[:nf], label='fit(real)')

and similarly

```
plt.plot(fr, data[nf:], label='data(imag)')
plt.plot(fr, result.best_fit[nf:], label='fit(imag)')
```

Note that I think you're going to want to allow `m` to be negative (or maybe I misuderstand your model).   I did not work carefully on getting a great fit, but I think this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve anything. The fit is still way off. I think  our approach is wrong. Also **tau** and **m** are physical properties that cannot be negative.

Comment: Well, I think it does sort of explain how to deal with fitting complex data, which was a substantial part of your question. Why your model does not match your data with parameters that you think are reasonable is somewhat harder to answer  -- how would we know that model function is actually correct?  That is, we can answer questions about how to use the tools, but it is much harder to address whether the results are sensible.

Comment: You are right, the data don’t fit this model. Unfortunately, I had it very wrong in my mind. It’s just like fitting a linear function on a power law data!